# Excel: Is there a way to sum n+1 cells if n cells meet criteria in a row?

Tags: excel, count, countif

[image: Example here]

Is there a way to sum every other cell in a row if adjacent cell meets certain criteria?
In the example I am looking for sum of BizB1 hours, which would be 47. What would give out this 47?
I've tired this one, but it just sums up every other cell, no condition in it:

> =SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($B$2:$U$2),2)=0,$B$2:$U$2,0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS with offset ranges:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:U2,A2:T2,"BizB1")
```

A mini example:
[image]

Comment: I did not know you could sumif offset ranges, omg. I though ranges had to have same cell count and same origin/end column/row. Thumbs up